# Whats the difference between Method and Functions in AwesomeWM

Tags: lua, awesome-wm

In each class of [AwesomeWM documents](https://awesomewm.org/doc/api/classes/screen.html) there is two section. Methods and Functions. Whats the difference between the two. I searched in the lua document and can't found anything there either. Here is a sample

#### Functions:

```
awful.screen.getbycoord (x, y)  Return the screen index corresponding to the given (pixel) coordinates.
awful.screen.focus (_screen)    Move the focus to a screen.
```

#### Methods

```
screen:instances ()     Get the number of instances.
screen:screen ()    Iterate over screens.
screen:count ()     Get the number of screens.
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

https://www.codecademy.com/article/fwd-js-methods-functions

Function — a set of instructions that **perform a task**.

Method — a set of instructions that **are associated with an object**.

Comment: Thanks. Maybe writing more instead of linking